# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mainPrincipal$ en Apace Spark

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark, cluster

Hola ante todo gracias.

Presento problemas al ejecutar el siguiente código en un cluster con Spark,
si lo ejecuto como master("local[*]") no da problemas todo perfecto, pero una vez que lo ejecuto de la siguiente forma

> /home/cluster/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.8.176.90:7077 --class mainPrincipar nombreDelJAR.jar nombredelfichero.csv

presenta el siguente error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ..... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mainPrincipal$
>
> at mainPrincipal$$anonfun$2.apply(mainPrincipal.scala.25) que es la línea que dice         "val tuplas = datos.map{row => parseTupla(row)}"

este es mi código:

```
object mainPrincipal {
  
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
                            .builder()
                            .appName("Nombre de la Aplicación")
                            .getOrCreate()    

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val nombreDelfichero = args(0)
   
    import spark.implicits._

    val datos = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").csv(nombreDelfichero)
    
    val tuplas = datos.map{row => parseTupla(row)} //RDD de Tupla(id: Long, valores: Seq[Double])
    tuplas.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    
    tuplas.foreach( element1 =>{
      println("Id "+element1._1.toString) 
    }
  }    

  case class Tupla(id: Long, valores: Seq[Double]) extends Serializable

  def parseTupla(row: Row): Tupla ={
    var coordenadas : Seq[Double] = Seq.empty[Double]

    val cant = row.size
    val id = row.getString(cant-1).toLong
    for(i <- 0 until cant-1)
    {
      coordenadas = coordenadas :+ row.getString(i).toDouble
    }

    Tupla( id,coordenadas)
  }
}
```

he consultados temas pero son parecidos y aun no tengo solución, agradecería la cooperación, lo antes posible y le reitero las gracias.

Comment: Tu cluster no está viendo el fichero .jar. ¿Cómo se supone que lo estás compartiendo? Prueba a cambiar `row => parseTupla(row)` por `parseTupla` sin más.

Comment: Bueno el ejecuta una primera linea donde imprimo el nombre del algoritmo, y luego es que da ese error en las linas posteriores que son las que publiqué, pruebo lo que me comentas. Muchas gracias por su aporte.

Comment: ChemaCortes gracias por tu aporte no me funcionó, pero partiendo de ahí se me ocurrió y ya lo logré resolver, pues introduje el código de la función parseTupla dentro del map, en la compilación de jar puse scala en compile y no provide como lo estaba haciendo